# How to convert char[] to UTF8 to avoid illegal continuation byte error in JNI

Tags: string, encoding, utf-8, java-native-interface, arrays

Using JNI, I'm passing values from a file to java.
However there are times that this error/warning would occur:

```
JNI WARNING: illegal continuation byte 0xc0
             string: '���������������������'
              in Lcom/package/project/parser;.getSong (Lcom/package/project/vo/songVo;Ljava/lang/String;)I (NewStringUTF)
```

I've read that there're some instances that the string fetched would not be in UTF8, if so, how can I convert and pass parsed char[] to string to avoid this error/warning again?

Comment: Do you know which encoding the data actually is?

Comment: The files could have different encodings, it's better to expect that because I'm parsing files from different sources, so it could have special characters, etc.

...

I've read this (http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/cb897211c719fbe8), but how do I "convert this string into UTF8 (aka "multibyte") first, then 
call NewStringUTF()."...?

Comment: So it could be *any* encoding and you don't actually know it? Do you **need** to handle that data as a `String`?

Comment: Yes, Jstring then add this as String in an object class.
Right now I'm passing Jstring like this:


                    (*env)->SetObjectField(env, allValues, fieldTitle, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, song->header->title));

Comment: As the name implies `NewStringUTF` only works for UTF-8 encoded data. If your data is not UTF-8 encoded and you don't know the encoding, then you **can't** reliably decode it!

Comment: Or, to check first if string is UTF-8 or -16 etc. then decode...?

Comment: @IsisBlack let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1832/discussion-between-joachim-sauer-and-isisblack)

Answer (score 0):

that is because your char[] is not a valid modifed-utf8, check this out.

[Unicode const char* to JString using JNI and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990038/unicode-const-char-to-jstring-using-jni-and-c/60629336#60629336)