# Unicode const char* to JString using JNI and C++

Tags: c++, unicode, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Simple question. How can I get a jstring out of a unicode const char*, using JNI and C++?

Here's my issue, and what I have already tried:

```
const char* value = (some value from server);
(*env)->NewStringUTF(value);
```

The issue here is that NewStringUTF returns a UTF string, and it does not like some of the non-UTF8 characters (kind of obvious, but worth a simple try).

Attempt 2, using NewString:

```
const char* value = (some value from server);
(*env)->NewString(value, strlen(value));
```

While NewString accepts and returns a unicode string, the strlen(value) method does not work because it requires a jsize param instead of just a good ol' size_t or length.

How do we get a jsize? According to the (very very small amount of) documentation and online examples, you can get the jsize out of a jIntArray.
I can't find information on how to convert a const char* to jarray of some sort, and this might be a bad idea anyways.

The other option would be to get the jsize out of the int in size_t, which I haven't succeed at yet either.

Has anyone come across this issue, or has suggestions on how to get around it?
It seems like jsize is the key I'm missing for the unicode conversion.
Also, I'm using JNI and the Android NDK, in case it helps anyone.

Thanks.

**Edit**
I just realized NewString is also expecting a jchar*, so its signature is (jchar*, jsize). This means that even with the jsize the const char* does not compile.

**Edit 2**
Here's the exception being thrown at runtime when using the NewStringUTF method. This is related to what @fadden is talking about:

```
JNI WARNING: NewStringUTF input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xb7 03string: ' : Method(d6, us-dev1-api, 0), , 訩�x�m�P)
```

Comment: Please add information about *how* you have tried to get a jsize out of the size_t and what problems exactly you had with it. Also, NewStringUTF() does *not* return a UTF string it return a Java String constructed out out UTF characters (Sorry for the previous inclomplete comment, hit return accidentally)

Comment: what? Can you elaborate that answer please?

Comment: Unicode string is never a `const char*`. It may be `const wchar_t*` or `const WCHAR*`, if your server runs Windows.

Comment: My understanding is that in JNI there's only UTF8 and Unicode, right? The UTF8 method says there are unknown characters in the set, which means it is expecting unicode, right? Sorry, I've been spinning on this for days so I might be getting a messed up logic now.

Comment: If the UTF8 methid complains, that does not necessarily mean that it's expecting unicode. It only means that your input is not in UTF encoding. If you have a char * and not a wchar_t * as @AlexCohn has pointed out, that's the method to use. But you have to make sure the string is UTF encoded, using some other function to convert it if necessary before passing it to NewStringUTF.

Comment: So if at runtime I get an error that the character set is not utf8, how can I convert it from whatever it is to utf8?

Comment: Sorry, c++ is not my specialty. I know java and I just need this for the ndk in an android app

Comment: There is a lot of misinformation flying around in here, `wchar_t` is the 16 bit type used for UTF16 on Windows. It is not synonymous with Unicode as Microsoft would like us all to think. UTF8 strings can be perfectly well represented as an array of `char`.

Comment: so any suggestion on how to get this const char* that contains non-utf8 characters into a jstring? that's all I care about at this point

Comment: @sjdowling but to be able to use it with NewStringUnicode() you would declare wchar_t * and make sure that what's in it is in Unicode encoding. The jchar used in the function declaration is a typedef to some 2-byte entity just as wchar_t is.

Comment: @TooManyEduardos converting your char * to UTF encoding has nothing to do with JNI. You have to check what functions your C library offers for this.

Comment: Can you please explain where these strings come from, and which encoding they use? Yes, JNI can create java.lang.String only from UTF8 or UCS16. But your input may be something else.

Comment: The const char* come from a .so library in the JNI, which is an encrypted version of a string coming from a server. The strings are supposed to be unicode, and all I really need to do is pass these strings (const char*) to java and use them there.

Comment: @user2543253 I don't see any part of [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewStringUTF) that mentions `NewStringUnicode`, or any method that takes a `jchar`.

Comment: To be clear, JNI supports "modified" UTF-8 (null is remapped, and non-BMP values are encoded as surrogate pairs) and UTF-16. Both are methods for encoding Unicode code points. Saying that a string is "unicode" doesn't reveal anything about the actual encoding. If the VM's NewStringUTF function is rejecting the string, then it's not in MUTF-8 format, and will need to be converted. Providing a hex dump of a string that is being rejected might be informative.

Comment: @sjdownling sorry, it's just called NewString

Comment: I would suggest simply to try an obvious option, `(*env)->NewString((jchar*)value, 5)` - and see if on the Java side you get a readable string (this assumes that the actual string is at least 5 letters long).

Comment: @AlexCohn I found a number that works and this compiles and runs. However, now this method converts the characters to what seem to be chinese and special characters (no joke).  So I'm not sure this approach with NewString works now

Comment: Well, this means that the string is not "Unicode" in the sense that we usually attribute to this term. Maybe the string is simply `char*`? What happens when you print the `value` with `"%s"` format via `__android_log_print()`?

Comment: `unicode const char*` doesn't make sense. `non-UTF8 characters` doesn't  make sense. Unicode is a character set. UTF-8 is an encoding that produces a sequence bytes from Unicode characters. You have to know the encoding and character set of your source data. (Then, often the easiest thing to do is to create a jByteArray, pass it back to Java and convert it there to a Java string.)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message shows, your char* is not a valid Modifed-utf8, so the JVM aborted.

You got two methods to avoid them.

1. check char* content to avoid a crash.

the check logic in android ART check_jni.cc is as following
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/35e827a/runtime/check_jni.cc#1273

```cpp
jstring toJString(JNIEnv* env, const char* bytes) {
    const char* error = nullptr;
    auto utf8 = CheckUtfBytes(bytes, &error);
    if (error) {
        std::ostringstream msg;
        msg << error << " 0x" << std::hex << static_cast<int>(utf8);
        throw std::system_error(-1, std::generic_category(), msg.str());
    } else {
        return env->NewStringUTF(bytes);
    }
```

This way, you always get a valid `jstring`.

2. Using String constructor to build from a `jbyteArray`.

```cpp
jstring toJString(JNIEnv *env, const char *pat) {
    int len = strlen(pat);
    jbyteArray bytes = env->NewByteArray(len);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(bytes, 0, len, (jbyte *) pat);
    jstring encoding = env->NewStringUTF("utf-8");
    jstring jstr = (jstring) env->NewObject(java_lang_String_class,
            java_lang_String_init, bytes, encoding);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(encoding);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(bytes);
    return jstr;
}
```

This way, you just avoid the crash, but the string may be still not valid, and you copy memory twice, which performs badly.

plus the code:

```
inline bool checkUtfBytes(const char* bytes) {
  while (*bytes != '\0') {
    const uint8_t* utf8 = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(bytes++);
    // Switch on the high four bits.
    switch (*utf8 >> 4) {
      case 0x00:
      case 0x01:
      case 0x02:
      case 0x03:
      case 0x04:
      case 0x05:
      case 0x06:
      case 0x07:
        // Bit pattern 0xxx. No need for any extra bytes.
        break;
      case 0x08:
      case 0x09:
      case 0x0a:
      case 0x0b:
        // Bit patterns 10xx, which are illegal start bytes.
        return false;
      case 0x0f:
        // Bit pattern 1111, which might be the start of a 4 byte sequence.
        if ((*utf8 & 0x08) == 0) {
          // Bit pattern 1111 0xxx, which is the start of a 4 byte sequence.
          // We consume one continuation byte here, and fall through to consume two more.
          utf8 = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(bytes++);
          if ((*utf8 & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
            return false;
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
        // Fall through to the cases below to consume two more continuation bytes.
      case 0x0e:
        // Bit pattern 1110, so there are two additional bytes.
        utf8 = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(bytes++);
        if ((*utf8 & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
          return false;
        }
        // Fall through to consume one more continuation byte.
      case 0x0c:
      case 0x0d:
        // Bit pattern 110x, so there is one additional byte.
        utf8 = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(bytes++);
        if ((*utf8 & 0xc0) != 0x80) {
          return false;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```